# double valued gauge in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

Does anyone know of a double valued gauge in wxPython? I would like to show the range of a set of data that has been selected,  I have the max and min values of the gauge and then I'd like to highlight the region of the gauge between two values. The normal wx.Gauge highlights from the gauge minimum (always the bottom of the gauge) to the set value.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any built-in widgets with the appearance of wx.Gauge that can do what you're looking for.

One option with a different appearance is [RulerCtrl](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.agw.rulerctrl.RulerCtrl-class.html), which can give you two value indicators on a scale with whatever range you want.  It just takes a bit of extra work to adapt it since not all of its properties are exposed in the listed methods.  Quick example:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.rulerctrl as rc

class MinMax(rc.RulerCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent, range_min, range_max, orient=wx.HORIZONTAL):
        rc.RulerCtrl.__init__(self, parent, orient)

        self.SetRange(range_min, range_max)
        self.LabelMinor(False)
        self.range_min = range_min
        self.range_max = range_max

        self.AddIndicator(wx.NewId(), range_min)
        self.AddIndicator(wx.NewId(), range_max)

        self.Bind(rc.EVT_INDICATOR_CHANGING, self.OnIndicatorChanging)

    def GetMinIndicatorValue(self):
        return self._indicators[0]._value

    def GetMaxIndicatorValue(self):
        return self._indicators[1]._value

    def SetMinIndicatorValue(self, value):
        # Value must be within range and <= Max indicator value.
        if value < self.range_min or value > self.GetMaxIndicatorValue():
            raise ValueError('Out of bounds!')
        self._indicators[0]._value=value
        self.Refresh()

    def SetMaxIndicatorValue(self, value):
        # Value must be within range and >= Min indicator value.
        if value > self.range_max or value < self.GetMinIndicatorValue():
            raise ValueError('Out of bounds!')
        self._indicators[1]._value=value
        self.Refresh()

    def OnIndicatorChanging(self, evt):
        # Eat the event so the user can't change values manually.
        # Do some validation here and evt.Skip() if you want to allow it.
        # Related: EVT_INDICATOR_CHANGED
        pass


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title)

        self.minmax = MinMax(self, 0, 100)
        self.minmax.SetSpacing(20)
        self.minmax.SetMinIndicatorValue(30)
        self.minmax.SetMaxIndicatorValue(84)
        self.Show()

app = wx.App(redirect=False) 
frame = MainWindow(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Range Indicator") 
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks, that will do the trick.  Just showing the region is fine.

Comment: @mor22 You're welcome.  You can probably catch the paint event and draw a colored line between the two indicators if you need to make it more clear what's being represented.